# a short simulation in numpy/python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, python-2.7, loops, numpy

I have given an array with 3 rows:

```
import numpy as np  

data = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
              [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
              [4, 3, 5, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]])

print (data)
```

I have to apply this function for a given array:

```
def simu(d):
    if not np.isnan(np.sum(d)):
        a = d[1:4].mean()
        b = d[3:6].mean()
        c = d[6:9].mean()
        res = [[a,b,c]]        
    else:
        res = 'error'
    return res
```

If there is not `nan` for a `data` row, the `simu` function calculates three values. If `nan` present in that row, it yields `error`.

`1st` row, do not have `nan` so, 3 values can be calculated for row `1st` with out error. These 3 values are to be used to replace `nan` values in `2nd` row. Then calculate `simu` function for row `2nd`.

The `nan` values in 3rd row are to be replaced by calculated 3 values from 1st and 2nd rows. Then calculate `simu` function for row3.

I tried as follows:

```
for d in data:
    d = d.reshape(-1,9)
    print (d)
    this_frame = data[0]
    print (this_frame)
    this_res = simu(this_frame)
    print (this_res)
    if np.isnan(np.sum(d)):
       ans = np.place(d, np.isnan(d), this_res)
       print (ans)
```

The expected output is 9 values from the for loop:

```
[[3.0, 5.0, 8.0]]
[[3.0, 5.0, 5.33]]
[[3.66, 5.33, 4.44]]
```

edit: some try:

```
results = []
currentStep = data[0]
for i in range(data.shape[0]):
    pred = simu(currentStep)
    results.append(pred)
    results = [results, pred]  
print (results)
```

Comment: Is the structure of the array always the same, such that always in the first row there are no NaNs, in the second 3, in the third 6?

Comment: @Axel yes, as you mentioned.

Comment: And in your `simu` function it is intended, that the values in the first column are never used?

Comment: yes, but the `simu` function is unchangeable to solve the question.

Comment: Ok you can have a look at my answer. However this assumes you will have the same structure in `data`. If this is not working let me know, what possible differences are there for the `data` array, so we can find a solution that works in a broader context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a list that you push the results to and then use this `results` array to change the `data` array according to your rule:

```
results = simu(data[0,:])[0]
for i in range(1,data.shape[0]):
    data[i,data.shape[1]-3*i:] = results
    results.extend(simu(data[i,:])[0])

res_arr = np.asarray(results).reshape(3,3)
print(res_arr)
```

You can test this [here](https://repl.it/@AxelFiedler1/WebbedMetallicLanserver-1).

Comment: Ah I changed the `simu` function so that it returned `[a,b,c]` instead of `[[a,b,c]]`. I will update my answer.

Comment: How do you like the updated solution? I removed the second loop and used a list as you suggested with your edit.